# Stop Logo from moving

Tags: css, wordpress

Please check [this website](http://www.macmetro.com/contact).

If you hover your cursor over the logo, it moves up and down, please tell me how I can stop it moving. The only moving piece is the icon in the logo.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include code in the question it self. Links to your website will be useless to other users here once you have fixed your website. Even worse it gives us a moving target to hit aas you try fixing it. Please read the StackOverflow help and take the tour to get a better idea on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 3):

Ill save you some hustle,

The 2 lines of Text **MacMetro** in the logo are not in the same position hence why the text is moving up and down. I know this because i checked. Its probably off by a few pixels.

[image]

Edit the logo in a paint package and move the 2nd text down a bit or 1st up a bit to match each others position perfectly. Depending on what brand Paint Package you may use there may be a tool to align the text perfectly for you

Comment: The text isn't moving on my Mac, now it's the laptop moving up and down.

Comment: that's because in your original css the whole logo was not positioned properly so it gives you the impression that the text is ok. When i checked it was about 80 pixels height and you had something like a 36px split. No matter what you do it will always be the computer screens going up or down or the text. The below answer with (Two Issues) is correct however you just need to fix the text now like i explained. zoom in on your browser and check the pic in my answer. you will clear see a gap in the text's. the 2nd text is higher than the 1st. only a few pixels but its noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1.) You need the height of this element to be one more pixel

```
.site-title a {
    height: 37px;
}
```

2.) You'll need to fix the background image sprite text

Comment: I have a folder called css which has style.css inside of it and 2 other files in the root called style.css and style.scss, which one do I edit? For the number 2, where would I fix that?

Comment: The CSS is in here: http://www.macmetro.com/wp-content/themes/macmetro/style.css?ver=4.1.1 - For the image, you'll have to fix it in an image editor.

Comment: .site-title a {
  width: 213px;
  height: 37px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 28px 0 0 0;
  background: url(assets/logo.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  text-indent: -9999px; }